# Como almacenar un blob de sqlite con swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, blob

Desde mi aplicación recibo imágenes al consumir un servicio web. Debo almacenar dichas imágenes en la base de datos sqlite en un campo `blob`.

Aquí esta la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trate de utilizar `NSData` para almacenar el `blob`.

Aquí esta lo que he intentado:

```
let image = UIImage(data: decodedData)
let data = image!.pngData()! as NSData
let recurso1 = Recurso(idRecurso: 1, recurso: "paisaje1", _extension: "png", contenido: data)

if !dataManager.insertRecurso(db, recurso: recurso1) {
    print("No se pudo registrar recurso")
}
```

Aquí esta la función del insert:

```
let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(-1, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)

func insertRecurso(_ db: OpaquePointer?, recurso: Recurso) -> Bool {
    var stmt: OpaquePointer? = nil;
    let sql = "INSERT INTO recurso(idRecurso, recurso, extension, contenido) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";

    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 0, Int32(recurso.idRecurso))
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, recurso.recurso, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, recurso._extension, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
        sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 3, recurso.contenido.bytes, Int32(recurso.contenido.length), SQLITE_TRANSIENT)

        if sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE {
            let errorMessage = String.init(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
            print("Error al ejecutar insert:", errorMessage)
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
            return false;
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
        return true
    } else {
        let errorMessage = String.init(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
        print("Error al preparar sentencia:", errorMessage)
        return false
    }
}
```

Siempre obtengo el mismo error:

`Error al ejecutar insert:` **datatype mismatch**

Estoy seguro que la imagen y la conexión a la base de datos son correctas.

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi error fue en el numero del parámetro. Los parámetros deben empezar con el indice 1 y no 0.

```
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, Int32(recurso.idRecurso))
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, recurso.recurso, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, recurso._extension, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 4, recurso.contenido.bytes, Int32(recurso.contenido.length), SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
```

Es fácil confundirse porque para obtener  los resultados de una consulta el indice de la columna comienza en 0.